# Why does git log --since not include the commits that I expect?

Tags: git, git-log

I wanted to get a list of all my commits to [a repository](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev) since the start of the year.  I tried with the obvious command, but it doesn't include any of them:

```
$ git log --pretty='format:%h %ae %cI %s' --author=cam@mcc.id.au --since=2017-01-01
$
```

Oddly, I have to use `--since=2016-12-19`, which gets me some of them:

```
$ git log --pretty='format:%h %ae %cI %s' --author=cam@mcc.id.au --since=2016-12-20
$ git log --pretty='format:%h %ae %cI %s' --author=cam@mcc.id.au --since=2016-12-19
61569b5 cam@mcc.id.au 2017-01-02T16:25:22+08:00 Bug 1324624 - Tweak stylo crashtest assertion annotations a bit more.
7fca5ff cam@mcc.id.au 2016-12-29T16:32:01+08:00 Bug 1323892 - Followup to disable one more crashtest under stylo.
cd875e7 cam@mcc.id.au 2016-12-28T17:50:44+08:00 Bug 1326023 - Make Element::GetBindingURL return a strong reference. r=smaug
3c057d1 cam@mcc.id.au 2017-01-02T15:44:23+08:00 Bug 1323717 - Re-enable 1290994-4.html. r=manishearth
7a45228 cam@mcc.id.au 2016-12-28T17:50:44+08:00 Bug 1326023 - Make Element::GetBindingURL return a strong reference. r=smaug
171e45e cam@mcc.id.au 2017-01-03T18:35:15+08:00 Bug 1328223 - stylo: Ignore invalid URLs from @import rules. r=emilio
$
```

But it's not all of them:

```
$ git log --pretty='format:%h %ae %cI %s' --author=cam@mcc.id.au | grep 2017- | wc -l
19
```

What's going on here?  Does `--since` do something other than just remove commits from the output that are earlier than the given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse (me, I'm in the "worse" camp), git defaults to the current time of day when you specify a date.  Try `--since='midnight 2016-12-20'`

... okay.  I haven't deciphered the code yet, but this looks awfully good for it:

```
~/src/gecko-dev$ lgdo @ --pretty=%h%x09%aI%x09%cI%x09%ae
*   1e82e8d0792b        2017-01-06T10:59:19-05:00       2017-01-06T10:59:19-05:00       ihsiao@mozilla.com
|\  
| * cddd3c28b212        2017-01-06T22:10:08+11:00       2017-01-06T22:10:08+11:00       me@upsuper.org
| * c337ff9019fb        2016-11-21T15:58:37-08:00       2016-11-21T15:58:37-08:00       olucafont6@yahoo.com
| * aa46f91d69e7        2017-01-05T17:14:46+01:00       2017-01-05T17:14:46+01:00       benj@benj.me
| * d1ef4e265960        2017-01-06T21:12:08+11:00       2017-01-06T21:12:08+11:00       me@upsuper.org
| * 76040295f609        2017-01-06T21:12:08+11:00       2017-01-06T21:12:08+11:00       me@upsuper.org
| * 1b2b0886c923        2017-01-06T21:12:08+11:00       2017-01-06T21:12:08+11:00       me@upsuper.org
| * 41782ed8bfb7        2017-01-06T15:30:31+08:00       2017-01-06T15:30:31+08:00       cam@mcc.id.au
| * 318a182e13bb        2017-01-06T15:29:47+08:00       2017-01-06T15:29:47+08:00       cam@mcc.id.au
| * b54b74578c69        2017-01-06T15:21:19+08:00       2017-01-06T15:21:19+08:00       cam@mcc.id.au
| * 076ab8862963        2017-01-06T15:05:24+08:00       2017-01-06T15:05:24+08:00       cam@mcc.id.au
| * 13ce7a2e81b0        2017-01-06T15:05:24+08:00       2017-01-06T15:05:24+08:00       cam@mcc.id.au
```

Notice your commits are behind commit `c337ff9`, dated 2016-11-21.  I'm betting there's an heuristic in there somewhere, that says if it encounters a commit dated more than a month before the cutoff it stops looking.

Comment: Using `--since='midnight 2017-01-01'` still shows me no commits from this year, though.

Comment: I see the docs don't say which timestamp gets checked, I'll see if I can't get that fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between author and commit date, here.  I did `git log --pretty='format:%h %ae %aI %s' --author=cam@mcc.id.au | grep 2017- | wc -l` and still get 19 commits with a printed date in 2017.

Comment: Of course this would have to be happening on a monster repo like that. It's still downloading. Git version & OS? This doesn't happen in anything I spot-checked.

Comment: :-) This is git 2.7.4 on Linux.  Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: [After @jthill's edit showing the the graph leading to my comments:] I reckon that is a good guess! Those commits were to an integration repository that periodically gets merged.  I'm not sure if it's a reasonable expectation that commit times (as opposed to author times) decrease monotonically as you traverse to parents. In any case, at this point it's probably worth filing a bug on git.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A few more notes, worthy of noting:

1. Git uses the commit date, not the author date, for the min and max age parameters (at least as of current nearly-2.12 source).  The output from the approxidate parser goes into `revs->max_age` (which is otherwise just -1) when using `--since`.  This really should be documented, and I'm not sure older Git versions do the same thing.
2. If `revs->limited` gets set, the function `limit_revs` gets called, which propagates an `UNINTERESTING` flag from parent commits to their children.  The `UNINTERESTING` flag also gets set when one commit is past the `max_age` setting.  This would prune all the children of a commit with a later committer date.  However, `revs->limited` should not actually be set here, as it's turned on instead by commit limiting operations (including `--ancestry-path` and `--simplify-by-decoration` for instance).
3. The internal function `get_revision_1` [does something similar if `revs->limited` is *not* set, except that it doesn't even add the parent commits](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/revision.c#L3093-L3107).

Even though commit dates would normally be nondecreasing, it seems incorrect to *assume* they're nondecreasing, since one can always *force* a particular commit date on any given commit—even a merge commit—through the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variable, for instance.  Or, even in the absence of malice, computer clocks are not always correct.  Should someone merge someone else's work when their computer is for some reason set to 1973, that doesn't put the other person's work in the past.

Comment: I think this is pretty clearly unintended behavior, there's a commit from Linus in 2008 (grep=bad.commit.dates) concluding "which causes occasional date mishaps to be handled cleanly". :-P